# Is there a way to create functions in a functionapp in the Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I'm trying to automate the creation of a serverless application using a cosmos db, static webpage, and functionapp (with at least one function) using a script which invokes a local installation of the Azure CLI. I've managed to create the db, the static page, and the functionapp using the CLI, but I can't find any resources for creating functions under the functionapp using the CLI (for example, a HTTP Trigger in JavaScript). Is there anyone that has tried this before/would be in a position to give some advice?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI is for deploying Azure Resources, not code.  Your best bet is to store your code in some sort of code repo like **GitHub** and then you can use the CLI to create and Azure Function that is configured for Continuous Deployment from that GitHub repo.  This way any updates to your code will automatically get deployed to your Function app.

An example can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-create-function-app-github-continuous

Comment: The link from the other asnwer shows you can use `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>` to deploy code

Answer (score 0):

Is the following guide useful for you? [create-first-azure-function-azure-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli)

You will need the core tools to have the func and you can script you way around the renaming step. In practice, you will most probably get the project from github or some place else and publish using the steps in the guide.

Comment: Better include the relevant command in this answer, `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>`. Links can go bad and Azure documentation is a bit... volatile